# How to prove that 1, sin(x), xsin(x) and cos(x) are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My attempt:

Suppose that $a\cdot 1 + b\cdot \sin(x) + c \cdot x\sin(x) + d\cdot \cos(x) = 0$.

Let $r = \sqrt{b^2 + d^2}$ and $\tan \phi = \frac{b}{d}$

Then $a + r \cdot \sin(x + \phi) + c\cdot x\sin(x) = 0$

I'm not sure where to go from here, or even if I'm on the right track.

Could somebody please help?

Comment: Look up Wronskian.

Comment: If they are linearly independent, then your equation must equal 0 for all x.  choose some convenient values for x, and and show that you can create at least 4 independent vectors choosing different values of x.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with the Wronskiansk, that makes things easier.

Otherwise, let 
$$a+b \sin(x) +c x \sin(x) +d \cos(x)=0$$

and plug in $x=0, x= \pi, x =\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $x =-\frac{\pi}{2}$. You get a system which is easy to solve for $a,b,c,d$.

**Note:** $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ together with $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ already give you $b=0$. This reduces the rest of the system to a system with 3 variables.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+b\sin(x)+cx\sin(x)+d\cos(x)=0$. Let $x=0$ and you get $a+d=0$. Let $x=\pi$ and you get $a-d=0$. Thus $a=d=0$.

So $b\sin(x)+cx\sin(x)=0$. Let $x=\pi/2$ and get $b+c\pi/2=0$. Let $x=-\pi/2$ and get $b-c\pi/2=0$. Thus $b=c=0$.